# Найти самый большой палиндром, полученный умножением двух трехзначных чисел:

Tags: java

У меня возникли проблемы с решением вопроса Эйлера Эйлера 4.Должно выводить 906609,мой вывод 580085.В чём может быть проблема?[java]

```
    public class Counter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Самый большой палиндром, полученный умножением двух трехзначных чисел: ");

        boolean end=false;
        for(int i=999;i>=100;i--)
        {
            for(int i2=999;i2>=100;i2--)
            {
                long curr=i2*i;
                if(IsPalindrom(curr))
                {
                    System.out.println(curr);
                    end=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(end)
                break;
        }

    }

    public static boolean IsPalindrom(long a)
    {
   String test = a + "";
   char b[] = test.toCharArray();
   for(int i=0;i<b.length/2;i++)
   {
       if(b[i] != b[b.length-i-1])
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
    return  true;
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы пробовали пользоваться отладчиком или хотя бы выводить на печать промежуточные значения, чтобы самостоятельно найти в чем проблема? Это очень полезный навык.

Comment: Вот первые пять итераций цикла: 580085 = 995 * 583 514415 = 995 * 517 906609 = 993 * 913 119911 = 991 * 121 282282 = 987 * 286

Comment: Да я пробовал,просто думал что если начну с максимальных значений то сразу найду макс палиндром

Comment: Хехе, все так думали  Но результат, например, 990*850 больше, чем 993*450, хотя вторая  пара встретится быстрее. Кстати, внутренний цикл лучше начинать с i, а не с 999, чтобы не проверять одинаковые пары по два раза.

Comment: @Артем Первые пять палиндромов. Итераций тут было сделано намного больше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто находится в твоем коде находится первое число-палиндром и программа завершается, а надо найти максимальный палиндром.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Counter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxPalindrom = 0;
        for (int i1 = 999; i1 >= 100; i1--) {
            for (int i2 = i1; i2 <= 999; i2++) {
                int curr = i2 * i1;
                if (isPalindrom(curr)) maxPalindrom = maxPalindrom<curr ? curr : maxPalindrom;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Самый большой палиндром, полученный умножением двух трехзначных чисел: " + maxPalindrom);
    }

    private static boolean isPalindrom(int value) {
        int numb = 0;
        for (int i=value; i!= 0; i/=10) numb=numb*10+i%10;        
        return numb == value;
    }

}
```

Ваш метод isPalindrom нерационален. Во-первых, для получения строки есть специальный метод String.valueOf, во-вторых, лонг вам в этом случае не нужен, поскольку произведение 999*999 вполне вмещается в инт, а он работает быстрее лонга, в-третьих, метод пишется с маленькой буквы, в-четвертых, поиск полиндрома числа путем его преобразования в строку - один из самых медленных способов поиска палиндрома. Кроме того, раз уж вы решили искать палиндром строки есть более простые способы, например, создать экземпляр класса StringBuilder, у которого есть метод reverse, переворачивающий строку. Более быстрый способ поиска числового палиндрома я привожу в коде. Также обратите внимание, что сократить время выполнения данного кода можно путем изменения направления вложенного цикла, что позволит вдвое сократить количество необходимых суммарных итераций. Над дальнейшими оптимизациями подумайте сами. И еще, не забывайте про инкапсуляцию, в виду которой метод isPalindrom следует сделать приватным, а не публичным (все таки инкапсуляция - принцип ооп). Удачи)